# NativeScript: max number of lines on a Label

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

If I add **textWrap="true"** to a Label, text is wrapped over several lines, so far so good.

But I have a very long string and our design only have room for two lines.
How do I limit the Label to max two lines?

I'd prefer not to set a height, since that would leave an empty line for texts that could fit on one line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try this:

For Android:

```
myLabel.android.setMaxLines(2);
```

For iOS:

```
myLabel.ios.numberOfLines = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, based your suggest I wrote an {N}-angular-directive for it:
https://gist.github.com/m-abs/ff9da8ed6c01c5c5115da37e4b535a2a

Answer (score 0):

To add an ellipsis('... ') at the end to indicate that the text is cutoff, implement the directive at the below link. The above one doesn't have any,

https://gist.github.com/EddyVerbruggen/8232252e3a4667e7e20916279f98d3fc